# ReactJS: How to pass function paramater dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to call Functions with parameter dynamically in ReactJS when selected a field

While selecting the element from the select drop-down, I stored that value in the state variables

```
<Select
onChange={e => setMessage(e.value)}
options={options}
>
```

After that, I need to call another function which this parameter and I did this, but it doesn't take any argument

```
<CallGetAMIDetails />
```

What will be the right syntax to execute the function with parameter

```
function CallGetAMIDetails(message)
```

This is wrong syntax <CallGetAMIDetails(message) />

Here is the full example code, what would be right thing to do to call this function `function CallGetAMIDetails(message)`

```
import React , { useState }from 'react';
import {DashboardLayout} from '../components/Layout';
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
    { value: 'ami-abc*', label: 'ami-abc' },
    { value: 'ami-xyz*', label: 'ami-xyz' },
]

const DiscoverAMIPage = () => {
    return (
        <DashboardLayout>
            <h2>Discovered AMI</h2>
            <Select
            onChange={e => setMessage(e.value)}
            options={options}
             />
        <CallGetAMIDetails />
        </DashboardLayout>
    )
}

  function CallGetAMIDetails(message) {
    console.log(this.message)
 }

export default DiscoverAMIPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CallGetAMIDetails` isn't a component, it's just a normal function.  You'd call it like any other function.  (Like how you call `setMessage` or `console.log` functions already.)  For example:

```
CallGetAMIDetails(someValue)
```

Are you trying to call it in the `onChange` handler?  If so, it would be like this:

```
onChange={e => {
  setMessage(e.value);
  CallGetAMIDetails(someValue);
}}
```

Basically you'd just wrap the change handler's function in curly braces `{}` so you could add another line of code to it.

Note of course that `someValue` is just a placeholder here, since I don't know what you want to actually pass to it.  If you're manually creating the function argument then it could be something like:

```
CallGetAMIDetails({ message: 'some message' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass your message state under CallGetAMIDetails components like this

```
<CallGetAMIDetails callMessage={message} />
```

And after use it in the component as props :

```
    CallGetAMIDetails = ({callMessage}) => {
       // Do somethings
    }
```

Every time your state is update with setMessage() useState function, your message state is updated and so your CallGetAMIDetails component too